# What would be a sql query to remove \n\r from the text?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL. My data has a column called `text`, which uses the TEXT data type.

There are several newlines for each record in this column. I want to remove all new lines with a sql query. How can I do that?

Comment: [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this one -

```
CREATE TABLE table1(column1 TEXT);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('text1\r\ntext2
text3');

SELECT * FROM table1;
--------
text1
text2
text3

UPDATE table1 SET column1 = REPLACE(column1, '\r\n', '');
SELECT * FROM table1;
--------
text1text2text3
```

Answer (score 15):

The previous suggestions did not work for me.  It only seems to work if I had actually typed the `\r` and `\n` text in as text. I found the following to work well -

```
replace(replace([MyFieldName],char(13),''),char(10),'')
```

I also created a calculated field in my table which uses this formula.  That way I can just reference that field in areas of my program that were breaking with the original field contents.

Answer (score 10):

Given suggestion i.e. `REPLACE(REPLACE(DBField, '\n', ''), '\r', '')` won't work if there are invisible html code like `\n \r`. For that you have to use char code.

Example:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(DBField, CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '')
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(FIELD, '\n', ''), '\r', '')
```

Comment: Agreed. This one guarantees those \n and \r characters (in any order and combination) will not escape from the replacement. `UPDATE table1 SET column1 = REPLACE(REPLACE(column1, '\n', ''), '\r', '');`

Answer (score 1):

i've tried all said here but neither worked for me, my DB is IBM Informix,
however i managed to solve the problem like this:

```
UPDATE personas SET foto_path = SUBSTRING(foto_path FROM 1 FOR LENGTH(foto_path) - 1);
```

Hope it helps other in similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REPLACE(text,'\n\r',' ')` for it.

Answer (score 0):

The above version with single backslash cleared up some for me but also had to run this to clear up the rest.

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(FIELD, '\\n', ''), '\\r', '')
```