# How do I get the first 160 characters from a SQL query and remove HTML?

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelpro

I've looked around to see if I could find a solution that directly addresses my question, but I can't seem to find it.

I'm querying my old DB and creating a new table that I can import into my new DB. I want to create a new field named `news_releases_summary` that is derived from `news_releases_body`, but only with the first 160 characters (for SEO meta desc) and ideally no HTML.

My current query looks like this. The function I'm having problems with is LTRIM RTRIM - I'm not even sure it's the right function for this job? * Note that I also need to remove \n\t because the final output will not validate as JSON if I don't do this.

```
SELECT  
FROM_UNIXTIME(exp_channel_titles.entry_date,'%m/%e/%Y %h:%i %p') AS entry_date,
exp_channel_titles.status, 
exp_channel_titles.title, 
exp_channel_data.field_id_66 AS news_releases_subtitle, 
exp_channel_data.field_id_65 AS news_releases_contact, 
REPLACE(replace(exp_channel_data.field_id_67,char(10),''),char(13),'') AS news_releases_body
LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(replace(exp_channel_data.field_id_67,char(10),''),char(13),''))) AS news_releases_summary
FROM exp_channel_data INNER JOIN exp_channel_titles 
ON exp_channel_data.entry_id = exp_channel_titles.entry_id 
WHERE exp_channel_data.channel_id = '21' 
ORDER BY exp_channel_titles.entry_date
```

**UPDATE**

This is where I am right now, but I'm getting an error "FUNCTION ee_2.strip_tags does not exist". Should I be including strip_tags function directly in the query? I'm using Sequel Pro on a Mac.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `strip_tags`($str text) RETURNS text
BEGIN
    DECLARE $start, $end INT DEFAULT 1;
    LOOP
        SET $start = LOCATE("<", $str, $start);
        IF (!$start) THEN RETURN $str; END IF;
        SET $end = LOCATE(">", $str, $start);
        IF (!$end) THEN SET $end = $start; END IF;
        SET $str = INSERT($str, $start, $end - $start + 1, "");
    END LOOP;
END;

SELECT  
FROM_UNIXTIME(exp_channel_titles.entry_date,'%m/%e/%Y %h:%i %p') AS entry_date,
exp_channel_titles.status, 
exp_channel_titles.title, 
exp_channel_data.field_id_66 AS news_releases_subtitle, 
exp_channel_data.field_id_65 AS news_releases_contact, 
REPLACE(REPLACE(exp_channel_data.field_id_67,char(10),''),char(13),'') AS news_releases_body,
LEFT(strip_tags(REPLACE(REPLACE(exp_channel_data.field_id_67,char(10),''),char(13),'')),160)     AS news_releases_summary 
FROM exp_channel_data INNER JOIN exp_channel_titles 
ON exp_channel_data.entry_id = exp_channel_titles.entry_id 
WHERE exp_channel_data.channel_id = '21' 
ORDER BY exp_channel_titles.entry_date
```

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Sequel Pro on a Mac

Comment: The only part of the query that does not work is the line with LTRIM

Comment: In that case, MySQL is your RDBMS.

Comment: Yes you're right, sorry answered your question incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use nested [`replace`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) calls to strip undesired newline characters; there are [questions on stack exchange that deal with this already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5828364/1030), though they use the literal `\n` and `\r` rather than using the [`char`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_char) function.

For stripping HTML entities there's not an easy way of doing it without rolling your function to do the business. Thankfully, [someone has done that for you as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2627940/1030).

Finally, if you only want 160 characters in the result, use the [`left`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left) function to limit the result to the leftmost 160 characters.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm getting close, but admittedly I do not understand how to use functions properly in my query. I inserted the 'strip_tags' function from this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627940/remove-html-tags-from-record but I'm getting an error: FUNCTION ee_2.strip_tags does not exist. I'm inserting the function before my query, but based on the error message, the function should be in a different location? Does anyone know where custom functions should live in Sequel Pro?